# May I wish all on Christianity SE a Merry Christmas and a Blessed New Year (2020)?

Tags: discussion

**May I wish all on Christianity SE a Merry Christmas and a Blessed New Year?**

Do not care about the votes, so Merry Christmas and may all have a Blessed New Year 2020!

I mean all and no one is exempt.

[image]

[Nativity of Jesus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nativity_of_Jesus#/media/File%3ABotticelli_Nativity.jpg), c. 1473-1475, by Botticelli

**Just want to keep Christ in Christmas!**

I wish to thank, especially all the moderators (past and present) for all their hard work on the site.

Special warm thanks and blessings goes out to both Nathaniel and Caleb for their past services and struggles. It has not been an easy year.

God Bless everyone and to all your families!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course you may!  And thank you for expressing your desire to keep Christ in Christmas.  Gets my "Amen".

Comment: Your sentiments are appreciated. Caleb and Nathaniel are very much missed. May you and your family be well in the coming year!

Comment: Well I posted my comment in the wrong spot for Ken but I’m sure he will see it. Best to you too Lesley!

Comment: @Kris - appreciate your good wishes. Have given you a little token of my appreciation in the Christianity Stack section.  God bless.

Answer (score 4):

And also with you.  That painting reminds me of how good a painter Botticelli was.  Our daughter and son in law visited us for just over a week with our first grand child (their daughter), a visit which brought great joy to our family.

The three of them: mother, father, child are a fine reflection of the holy family celebrated in that painting. (Sadly, no camels at our house ...)

Answer (score 0):

Merry Christmas, happy holidays, and a Blessed New Year!